# Can a variable be declared within a while loop?

Tags: php, while-loop

I am trying to understand the basic PHP code in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Z5dy7_u8os), which demonstrates how you can list all the positions of a specific string within a larger string (in this case, all the positions of $find within $string will be listed):

```
<?php

$find = 'is';
$find_leng = strlen($find);
$string = 'This is a string, and it is an example.';

while ($string_position = strpos($string, $find, $offset)) {
    echo '<strong>'.$find.'</strong> found at '.$string_position.'<br>';
    $offset = $string_position + $find_length;
}

?>
```

What confuses me is that within the () of the while-loop, it seems that a new variable $string_position is being declared. But doesn't the while-loop take an input of 0 or 1, a Boolean? The $string_position variable is not a true/false variable, it is meant to store the position of the string it is passed with the strpos() function.

The basic while-loop I'm used to uses a comparison operator like this one from from w3schools:

```
<?php 
$x = 1; 

while($x <= 5) {
    echo "The number is: $x <br>";
    $x++;
} 
?>
```

Can a variable be declared in a while-loop? And if that is the case, how does it work in this example? This is my first question on Stack Overflow so hopefully I'm posting this in the right place and it's not too newbie of a question.

Comment: Take a look into the manual of  [`strpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) You will see, that it will return FALSE, if no occurrences of the needle is found in the haystack. And since you always assign the offset in each iteration with the new found occurrence you will go through every match until it won't find the needle anymore and will return FALSE. So the variable will eventually hold FALSE, so the while loop stops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, while loops take boolean-like as arguments. By doing

```
while ($string_position = strpos($string, $find, $offset)) {
```

it first executes what is inside the parenthesis, then evaluates the result of that to determine if the loop should quit or not.

`strpos` will return False if the needle was not found, so `$string_position` will be false and as such the evaluation result will also be False and the loop will quit. If the needle is found, then loop continues after the attribution.

Also it should be noted that `strpos` might return a non-boolean that evaluates to False, so be careful with that construction.

[Reference on strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)

Comment: In the first pass through the loop, $string_position should equal 2 because 'is' is found at position 2 within the word 'This'. Because of that the while loop will take the argument 2, and next 5, and so on. Does the while-loop treat 1 and numbers greater than 1 as true?

Comment: Yes, any number that is not 0 is evalued as True. This will give you a broader idea of what is considered False in PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php

Answer (score 0):

In most programming languages, if a variable exists and isn't 0 or False, then it counts as a 1 or True.

In this example:

```
if ($str="hey"){
    echo $str;
};
```

It will output `hey` because the variable was successfully declared and isn't 0.